# Why ActionBar is Missing(Android) and how to add back button?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello to Stack Overflow community.

I have included the AppCompactActivity in my class but, the action bar still not showing in my app. And I also want to add back button at my action bar.

```
public class infoAplikasi extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    ...

}
```

How, to solve it and how to add the back button to main? Thanks.

Comment: what is the API level you have added in your manifest it should be 7 or up. Also it would be a good idea to share your manifest file

Comment: My API level is 21, I have changed the build tool version to "22.0.1" at build.gradle to use AppCompactActivity

Comment: Previously, the action bar is present, but recently it is missing. So, I thought using the AppCompactActivity can make it present back. That's why I changed the build tool version to "22.0.1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an `AppCompatActivity` means that you need to add a toolbar view in your `R.layout.info` to enable you to use an actionbar within your activity.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

and setting the toolbar to the activity is just calling the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` where you set the toolbar view in the parameter

[Go here](http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/) for more tutorial about adding a toolbar

and for the backbutton don't attach a navigation drawer to the toolbar.